# Ktor Exposed java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction in context

Tags: postgresql, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I'm building ktor server using postgress, exposed, and hikari cp. I was following this https://ktor.io/docs/interactive-website-add-persistence.html. But I encountered error that need to be explain in this thread.

I have datasource to get all users like :

```
override suspend fun getAllUsers(): Query = dbQuery {
    UserDao.selectAll()
}
```

Using this code, it will return error as follow:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction in context.`

But when I change the return value to List it's working fine. Can someone explain what is wrong with Query return value? Thank you

```
override suspend fun getAllUsers(): List<User> = dbQuery {
    UserDao.selectAll().map { 
        it.asUser()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't work with queries without transactions. So. The second example closes query and return user's list.

After obtaining the connection, all SQL statements should be placed inside a transaction:
[description here](https://ktor.io/docs/interactive-website-add-persistence.html#create_table)

Comment: but per documentation says
"In this code sample, the default database is passed explicitly to the transaction function. If you have only one database, you can omit it. In this case, Exposed automatically uses the last connected database for transactions."

Comment: This means that you can use **"transaction { }"** instead of **"transaction (database) { }"**.
But we can't use the Query object without a transaction because it's a prepared query against the database. When we use a map, we get data for objects.